# iOS Swift MKMapView set overlay in front of map, behind annotation view

Tags: ios, swift

Here's an image of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Basically, a "dimmed" map.

**The problem**: The user needs the capability to pan the map, so just adding a semi-transparent view over the map won't do. (Adding a view over the mapView means it won't be able to detect gestures.)

Things I've tried:

- Setting mapView `backgroundColor`
- Adding a semi-transparent view using `mapView.insertSubview`
- Setting mapView alpha (affects all children, i.e. annotation views)
- `MKOverlay` (I've only found ways to set a view/polygon by coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to subclass a view that you can add as a semi-transparent subview, and give it a new variable called "map". This `map` variable would be a reference to your actual map. Add gesture recognizers for the subview, and when some sort of gesture takes place, pass the gesture to the map.

or add the gesture recognizers to the subview, and in the gesture recognizer, say `map.runFunctionForThatGesture`

I haven't done this myself, but I think it should work

Comment: How do you get the annotations above the semi-transparent view?

Comment: @damionjn I'm not sure about that sorry :(